# Unable to retrieve image string from firebase using picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, picasso

I am making a chat app and using firebase to upload data, including the user's name, status and image as Strings. Name and status are working fine but the image is not loading at all. I think the code is correct but it is not able to retrieve the id of the image. The images are being uploaded in firebase without any issues. I am using Picasso to retrieve them. Please can you suggest why am I not able to retrieve the image?
This is my code

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
private TextView mName;
private TextView mStatus;
private Button mStatusBtn;
private Button mImageBtn;

private static final int GALLERY_PICK=1;
private StorageReference mImageStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mDisplayImage=(CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);
    mName= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settings_display_name);
    mStatus=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.setting_status);
    mStatusBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_status_btn);
    mImageBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.settings_img_btn);

    mImageStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mCurrentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String current_uid=mCurrentUser.getUid();



    mUserDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);

    mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final String image=dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            final String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image=dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

            mName.setText(name);
            mStatus.setText(status);

            if(!image.equals("default")) {

               

                Picasso.get().load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.dog).into(mDisplayImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {

                        Picasso.get().load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.dog).into(mDisplayImage);

                    }
                });

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    mStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String status_value=mStatus.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent status_intent=new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,StatusActivity.class);
            status_intent.putExtra("status_value",status_value);
            startActivity(status_intent);
        }
    });

    mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent= new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select Image "),GALLERY_PICK);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==GALLERY_PICK&& resultCode==RESULT_OK){

        Uri imageUri=data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(SettingsActivity.this);

    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this).create();
            dialog.setTitle("Uploading image...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while we upload your image");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();

            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            final File thumb_filePath= new File(resultUri.getPath());

            String current_user_id=mCurrentUser.getUid();

            Bitmap thumb_bitmap = new Compressor(SettingsActivity.this)
                    .setMaxWidth(200)
                    .setMaxHeight(200)
                    .setQuality(75)
                    .compressToBitmap(thumb_filePath);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumb_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            final byte[] thumb_byte = baos.toByteArray();

            StorageReference filepath=mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");
            final StorageReference thumb_filepath=mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("thumbs").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");

            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        final String download_url= task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        UploadTask uploadTask=thumb_filepath.putBytes(thumb_byte);
                        uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> thumb_task) {

                                String thumb_downloadUrl=thumb_task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                                if(thumb_task.isSuccessful()){

                                    Map update_hashMap=new HashMap<>();
                                    update_hashMap.put("image",download_url);
                                    update_hashMap.put("thumb_image",thumb_downloadUrl);

                                    mUserDatabase.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Success Uploading thumbnail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                }

                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Error in uploading thumbnail",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                        mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Successfuly Uploaded.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{

                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Error in uploading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                }
            });
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00BCD4"
tools:context=".SettingsActivity">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/settings_image"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="224dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settings_display_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="326dp"
    android:text="Display Name"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setting_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="301dp"
    android:text="@string/default_status"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings_img_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="204dp"
    android:text="Change Image" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings_status_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
    android:text="Change Status" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does `dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString()` return? Please also add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Please post the data of node

Comment: Below is the JSON format of the databse I'm referring to.


"Users" : {
    "P0EWILTmPZPoTm75agiQNQZ9B5u2" : {
      "image" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@d5fd49",
      "name" : "Chirag Garg",
      "online" : 1601449110407,
      "status" : "My name is Chirag",
      "thumb_image" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@447865f"
    },

Comment: why the image URL is a task? I guess you were not able to successfully upload and retrieve the image URL.

Comment: what should it be then instead of a task? The image is being successfully uploaded though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the `networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)`. You are basically skipping network and forcing Picasso for search in the disk. That's mean it is not communicating with firebase and thus the image is not loaded. For reference read the official documentation:

https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/NetworkPolicy.html

Comment: even with networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) removed, the problem still persists. I even tried using Glide instead of picasso and it had the same issue.

Comment: then i guess you are not retriving image link successfully from firebase.